# Dropdown elements (v-overflow-btn, v-date-picker) only partially displaying

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

The dropdown elements on my page (i.e., v-overflow-btn and v-date-picker) are automatically sized to 140px by 80px, even though I don't set any sizing limits in the vue component or its parents.

When I inspect the dropdown list created by v-overflow-btn, I can turn off the sizing settings (width: 140px, height: 80px) of the v-card, which appears to be a child of the v-select-list, and then the element displays like expected.  I can't figure out what to change in Vue to keep this automatic sizing from happening

```
<template>
    <div class="main">
        <v-container>
        <v-card  class="accent" height="100%" width="100%">
            <v-card-title>
                Create New Event
            </v-card-title>
            <v-container >
                <v-layout>
                    <v-card-text>
                        <v-form>
                           <v-overflow-btn 
                            label="Tournament Type" 
                            :items="tournamentOptions" 
                            v-model="newEvent.type" >
                           </v-overflow-btn>
                      </v-form>
                    </v-card-text>
                </v-layout>
            </v-container>
        </v-card>
        </v-container>
    </div>
</template>
```

styling from App.vue:

```
header {
  background-color: #2A7342;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:20px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2A7342;
}
.nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(216, 216, 216);
  cursor: pointer;
  color:rgb(44, 44, 44);
}
.nav li a:hover {
  color:rgb(44, 44, 44);
}
.router-link-active {
  background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
}
</style>
```

[devtools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAYwm.png)

Comment: Your `class="accent` isn't closed correctly, by the way.

Comment: Curiously, which version of vuetify are you on -- 1.5 or 2.0?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy version 2.0

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems when I run your code. Could you post a picture of the CSS sizes in the dev tools, it might help to figure out what's going on?

Comment: @skirtle The styling is just default except for what we've added on App.vue, which I added above.

Comment: You mentioned turning off the size settings of `140px` and `80px`. I assumed you meant within the dev tools? That's what I want to see. From looking at the selectors used and other styles applied it may be possible to deduce where these sizes are coming from.

Comment: @skirtle Gotcha. I posted a picture of the dev tools and you can see the size settings on v-card.

Comment: Everything you've posted makes me think this is coming from some custom CSS in one of your components. In the dev tools, if you look to the right of the sizes you'll see it says `<style>`. Click on that. It should jump you to the relevant `style` tag in the DOM. If you then expand that you should see all the other styles associated with that component, which may help to identify where this is coming from. If that doesn't work, just try searching through all files for the number `140`.